# How to show dimension members for which there are no values in fact in SSAS Multi-Dimensional?

Tags: sql, ssas, olap

I have two tables in my Ticket Management Application, "**ExpositionPeriods**" and "**OrganisedVisits**".

**ExpositionPeriods** - Defines the periods for which tickets can be purchased.

**OrganisedVisits** - Stores the tickets purchased information.

In the example below, we have 5 periods available, and tickets have been purchased for 2 of the periods.

[image]

The customer wants a report which shows "Number of visitors against each available period". That means if, for any period which doesn't have a visitor, the report should show "0" for that period. Something like this.

[image]

So far so good.  Since the production database is humongous (~500 GB), it is not advisable to report on this database directly. Things turn to be challenging when I create an OLAP cube out of this schema and try to achieve the same report functionality in the cube. It seems the cube actually performs an action similar to SQL INNER JOIN as opposed to a LEFT OUTER JOIN and hence I do not see those Periods for which there are no tickets sold.

[image]

Is this how SSAS actually behaves? Am I missing out any particular setting that will indicate the SSAS engine to process the cube in a different manner so as to include the missing periods as well? Please note, end customers don't have access to MDX/DAX scripts, they can only use the cube by drag-drop measure and dimensions like in Excel pivot table.

Answer (score 1):

In your image the browser is carrying out a non empty on rows on the date dimension. If you want to show the dates with no visitors then select the option to show empty cells.

Comment: It looks like when I select the option to show empty cells, those are displayed as NULL. Is there any way I can make those NULL values to display numeric 0?

Answer (score 0):

You can define such scope in "calculations" as

```
SCOPE 
([Measures].[Visitors]);
THIS=IIF(ISEMPTY([Measures].[Visitors]),0,[Measures].[Visitors]);
END SCOPE;
```

So you have zeros instead of nulls and side effect. You or customer can't hide empty cells, cause now it's not empty enough.